# Why does Python skip first element in string join statement?

Tags: python, string, join

Here's a simple example:

```
In [155]: exampleArray = bytearray([0xc0, 0xff, 0x01])
In [156]: exampleArray
Out[156]: bytearray(b'\xc0\xff\x01')
In [157]: print ' 0x'.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in exampleArray)
c0 0xff 0x01
```

but what I want is 
0xc0 0xff 0x01

Comment: Joins writes the `' 0x'` **between** the elements.

Comment: try `print(' '.join('0x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in exampleArray))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation of `str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join):

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable. A `TypeError` will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The **separator** between elements is the string providing this method.

So the `' 0x'` is a **separator** that is put **between the strings**. You can however easily solve this with:

```
print ' '.join('0x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in exampleArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.join()` only places the joiner **between** the joined elements. From the [`str.join()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> **The separator between elements** is the string providing this method.

(*Bold emphasis mine*).

Join on a space instead, and change the format to include the `0x` prefix:

```
' '.join('{:#04x}'.format(x) for x in exampleArray)
```

The `#` changes the format to include the `0x` prefix for you; do take into account that you need to adjust the field width to take the extra 2 characters into account (each field now takes up 4 characters, including the `0x` prefix).

Demo:

```
>>> exampleArray = bytearray([0xc0, 0xff, 0x01])
>>> print ' '.join('{:#04x}'.format(x) for x in exampleArray)
0xc0 0xff 0x01
```